# MS Visual Studio Express 2012 Desktop crashes every time I hover over variable in debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, crash

Example of code that causes crash

[image: When I hover over previousKey, it crashes]

When I hover over previousKey, it crashes

I used it a lot before, it was never crashing until now.

### Crash info

> Name of app event:   BEX
>
> Application name:   WDExpress.exe
>
> App version:    11.0.50727.42
>
> App timestamp:  503ebe9f
>
> Name of error module:   StackHash_0a9e
>
> Version of error module:    0.0.0.0
>
> Exception shift:    71d071c6
>
> Exception code: c0000005
>
> exception data: 00000008
>
> OS version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>
> Language code:  1049
>
> Additional data 1:  0a9e
>
> Additional data 2:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Additional data 3:  0a9e
>
> Additional data 4:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

### Event log says

> Application was terminated via unhandled exception
>
> Exception info: System.AccessViolationException
>
> Stack:    in
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.IVsCustomDataTip.DisplayDataTip()
> in
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.ShimQuickInfoSource.HandoffNoDefaultTipToDebugger(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.IQuickInfoSession)
> in
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.ShimQuickInfoSource.TryGetQuickInfoFromFilter(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.IQuickInfoSession,
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.TextSpan[], System.String
> ByRef)    in
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.ShimQuickInfoSource.AugmentQuickInfoSession(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.IQuickInfoSession,
> System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<System.Object>,
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITrackingSpan ByRef)    in
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Recalculate()
> in
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Start()
> in
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.DefaultQuickInfoController.OnTextView_MouseHover(System.Object,
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.MouseHoverEventArgs)    in
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.RaiseHoverEvents()
> in
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.OnHoverTimer(System.Object,
> System.EventArgs)
>
> in System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.FireTick(System.Object)
> in
>
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
> System.Object, Int32)    in
>
> MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
> System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
>
> in System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
>
> in
>
> System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
>
> in
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
> System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>
> in
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
> System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>
> in
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
> System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    in
> System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>
> in System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
>
> in System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32,
> IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
>
> in MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr,
> Boolean ByRef)    in
> MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)    in
>
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
> System.Object, Int32)
>
> in
> S.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
> System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
>
> in
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
> System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)    в
> MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>
> Internet advices to disable some data prevention thing for
> wdexpress.exe, but it says that it cant be disabled for this
> application
>
> win7x64sp1

It also freezes and crashes when I open the form edit tab, which is missing all text and doesnt respond to clicks.

> Name of event:    APPCRASH
>
> App name:   WDExpress.exe
>
> App version: 11.0.50727.42
>
> Name of error module:   StackHash_cdcd
>
> Exception code: c000041d
>
> Additional info 1:  cdcd
>
> Additional info 2:  cdcdb730d0d6bfcb220c35fc65530ab9
>
> Additional info 3:  422d
>
> Additional info 4:  422d51df37da39da33ec5e864c8278c3

Comment: Can you check event viewer to check logs?

Comment: Added the event viewer info @PratikGaikwad

Comment: @jstq, can you share me a simple sample? So I could debug it in my side. As you said that it worked well before, how about creating a new blank solution? And then add all project files to the new solution, debug it again. Or delete the .suo file, and then re-open the xxproj file, please also make sure that you use the default VS settings. Of course, if you have other VS machine, I think it could help you narrow down this issue using different Environments.

Comment: when I create new project, vs instantly freezes and then crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the VS crashed during you create a new simple project, you would think about the VS setup or others since actually you don't debug an app. It would be not the VS debugger tool issue. Do you agree with me?

TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings->select “No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings”->Choose a Default Collection of settings. And then run your VS as the admin, re-create a new simple app, test the result.

Please also make sure that it is not the performance issue, you could visit your task manager and close other third party processes which spend high Memory/CPU.

If still no help, I suggest you repair your VS, please also install the update 5 for your VS2012.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=48708

Comment: Simple pc reboot helped